# Speed up the Keras sequential model in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to decrease the execution time of the Keras sequential model that runs in a loop several times.

My training dataset shape: `(1,9526,32736,1) (1,ntimes,ngrid,1)`
and test data shape is `(1,1059,32736,1)`

The test data time dimension is not fixed (variable) but the `ngrid` is fixed.

I created a dummy dimension in the end so that when I call the training data in the for loop the dimension shape will be `(1,ntimes,1)`

This is the description of what model does:

1. First, the model does the convolution along the time axis for a single grid point.
2. Subtracts the output of the convolution from the input data.
3. Does the convolution (along the time axis) of the output from the second layer.

The above steps are repeated 32736 `ngrid` times.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Conv1D,subtract

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
 2.4.1

import tensorflow.keras as keras
print(keras.__version__)
 2.4.0

no_epochs = 1000
validation_split = 0
verbosity = 0

pred = np.ones(xtest.shape[1:3])
for i in tqdm(range(ngrid)):   
    keras.backend.clear_session()
    inputs = Input(shape=(None,1),batch_size=1,name='input_layer')
    smoth1 = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=90,padding='same',activation='linear')(inputs)
    diff = subtract([inputs, smoth1])
    smoth2 = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=30,padding='same',activation='linear')(diff)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=smoth2)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    model.fit(xtrain[:,:,i,:],ytrain[:,:,i,:],epochs=no_epochs,validation_split=validation_split,verbose=verbosity)
    pred[:,i] = model.predict(xtest[:,:,i,:]).squeeze()
    del model
```

I am looking for other alternatives that can speed up my code. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running on a gpu? based on your code it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I am running on CPU

Comment: Running on a GPU like the free one in colab will be the most dramatic way to increase your performance

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am running on the university server, where all the data is  located.

Comment: Are you able to move your model and weights to a GPU? Or is there not one available in the environment that you're using?

Comment: Yes, the environment does not have a GPU.

Comment: Are you able to use batch forwarding to decrease the load?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of batch forwarding.